# Deep access to the view in custom array adapter

Tags: android

```
    lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterview, View view,
                                           int position, long id) {        
                        doSomething();                 
                }
        });
```

That is my code of my main activity. I made a custom listview and of course, customized ArrayAdapter as well. And in each row of listview I have a progress bar, I set progress bar view in `ArrayAdapter` at `getView()` method. Like this is my ArrayAdapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
}
private void updateProgressBar(){
//blah blah
}
```

So my question is: When I execute `doSomething()` method by clicking on a row of listview at main Activity, it triggers the `updateProgressBar()` method in `ArrayAdapter` class and update the progress bar view in that row. So imagine if I click three row then three progress bar of each row will start running. How I possibly achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can get the item using the `adapter` and activate the `progressbar` of the specific item or you can add a `clicklistener` to each row when created and update it inside the `getview()`

I hope this helps

---

For example, suppose `lv` is a `ListView` and suppose that your `ProgressBar` is `invisible` and you are just going to make it `visible` when someone clicks on the item

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         doSomething(view, yourListArray.get(position), position);
    }
});
private void doSomething(View view, YourItem item, int position){
    ((ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.list_progress)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //do whatever you want here, you have the item, the view and even the position in case you need something
    //else, in fact this maybe should be a thread so whenever you finish doing whatever you want, in the
    //handler of the thread you make the ProgressBar invisible again
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Urhm can you give me example code of how adapter activate the progress bar of the specific item?

Comment: sure, sorry for the late response, i was away on the weekend. Ill edit the answer